# Action Bar Up button reserved space?

Tags: android, image, android-actionbar, drawable, back-button

I noticed that when you put a custom drawable in the actionBar, even when I don't set the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` the space in the action bar get's reserved for the icon. I have set the drawable in the style:

```
<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/someIcon</item>
```

Is it possible to somehow disable that the actionBar reserves the space for the icon when it is not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
```

Comment: no, this is not helping, the space is still reserved for the icon.